# SQL Reporting: Matrix Columns Merge

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, matrix

Hi I have data being returned and I put it in a matrix.  I have my rows set and my columns set.  I only have one column entitled "GTA" and a few rows.  My data is coming out like this for some reason.

```
          GTA  GTA  GTA
Answer  
========================
1          1            
1               2       
1          1            
1               2       
1               2       
1               2       
1          1            
1                    3
```

Whenever the value is different it dynamically makes a new column for it and does the above.. why?  Is there away I can get it looking like this:

```
          GTA
Answer  
==============
1          1            
1          2            
1          1            
1          2            
1          2            
1          2            
1          1            
1          3
```

Comment: It looks like I should be using a Table as opposed to a matrix....

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the table template.  The Matrix is for cross tab or pivot table style reports.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the Matrix control as a "design time pivot table".

If you don't know what a pivot table is or does, then you shouldn't be using the Matrix control.

Each column in the Matrix represents a grouping of the data.

With a table you are only grouping on rows, with a Matrix you are grouping on rows AND columns.